# How to slice numpy array with rows of varying length

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `arr` of numpy arrays each with varying length. I can get the shape of `arr`:

```
arr.shape

>>> (9,)
```

I can get the shape of one of the elements of `arr`:

```
arr[0].shape

>>> (6, 1, 2)
```

And I know that all such elements have shape `(n, 1, 2)`.

I want to slice `arr` to get a 1 dimensional result as follows:

```
arr[:,:,:,0]
```

But I get the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

**EDIT:** My original question was misleading. I want to do this slice so that I can *assign* values to the slice. So getting the slice in a new variable is not useful for my case. Essentially I want to do something like this in a simple one liner:

```
arr[:,:,:,0] = arr[:,:,:,0] - np.min(arr[:,:,:,0])
```

Comment: The element arrays have to be operated on individually.  It is basically a list of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your first (in fact all varying ones) dimension, and apply your transformation per static-shaped elements of `arr`

```py
import numpy as np
from random import randint

arr=np.array([np.random.randint(3,15, size=(randint(3,9),randint(3,7),randint(6,19))) for el in range(9)])

print(arr.shape)
print(arr[0].shape)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    arr[i][:,:,0]-=arr[i][:,:,0].min()
    print(arr[i][:,:,0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use *list comprehension* version of your solution.

```
desired_result = np.array([el[:,:,0] for el in arr])
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I made a mistake with the way I asked the question and now I've reframed it.